# Is it possible to remove signatures from a Transaction

Tags: transactions, signature, transaction

I have a Transaction object which has three signatures. I want to remove one of them. Is that possible?

Since it's an array, I've tried using pop but that isn't updating it.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

edit: I was using the Typescript web3.js library.

Comment: It'll help if you post a code example or even just say what language you are using

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't really make sense ? Why would you like to remove a signature ?
Signatures are added automaticaly (with null) when they are needed, and you have to sign transaction to add the signature data.
If you remove a signature, the transaction will fail for a missing signature.
If you think that there is a signature that should not be included in the transaction, check your instructions, this account might be used to pay some fees or something similar, and that's why it is included in the transaction.